# Mouse directives behave strangely in nested AngularJS environment

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to implement a nested tree structure in AngularJS. It consists of nodes which all get managed by the same controller type. You can find an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Yfmdy/2/

My problem is, that everytime a child node gets deleted and its parent's "children" array gets modified, all parents lose their ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave behaviors.

Has anyone an idea what to do about that? Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bug: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/963

Answer (score 0):

Use `$browser.defer` to emit `$childDeleted` event.
Set current element css to `display: none;` and force execute `ng-mouseleave`.

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ticore/Yfmdy/11/

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick. Still, I'd expect this to work properly without any further knowledge of the inner angularjs workings. However, adding a "real" jquery implementation fixes the issue as well: http://jsfiddle.net/Yfmdy/14/

Comment: I test [jsfiddle.net/Yfmdy/14](http://jsfiddle.net/Yfmdy/14/) in Chrome and Firefox, still not work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's a bug of browser javascript.

JavaScript MouseOver/Out event inconsist.

Pure js example here http://jsfiddle.net/GbuNn/6/